# Plugin Development: intercept Entry before returned to template

Tags: plugin-development, templating, elementcriteriamodel, hook

Is there a hook in Craft to intercept an Entry before being returned to a (front-end) template? Thinking here of ways we can manipulate what is being returned in the Element Criteria Model without affecting the underlying content.

Thoughts appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably depends on the specifics of what you're trying to accomplish, but your best bets I'm guessing would be to listen to some of the [element level events](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#element-api-events), make sure it's an entry and a site request, then do your logic.

[onBeforeBuildElementsQuery](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#elements-onBeforeBuildElementsQuery), [onBuildElementsQuery](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#elements-onBuildElementsQuery), and [onPopulateElements](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#elements-onPopulateElements) are potential candidates.